# Creating a list of matrices in R-programming

Tags: r, matrix

So I'm trying to create 10 separate 2x2 matrices with only the top left value changing.

I'm fairly new to this, but my best attempt:

x <- 1:10
A<- matrix(c(x,2,4,-1),nrow=2) but this makes 1 big 2-row matrix

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this, the result is a list containing 10 matrix :

```
x <- 1:10
A <- lapply(x, function(x) matrix(c(x,2,4,-1),nrow=2))
A[[1]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    4
## [2,]    2   -1

A[[2]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    2    4
## [2,]    2   -1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you by any chance know how to find the svd of each matrix? I tried svd(A[1]) but received: Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'

Comment: `A[1]` is a list, but `A[[1]]` is a matrix, try `class(A[1])` and `class(A[[1]])`, so `svd(A[[1]])` will work.